# How to get the actual command IntelliJ 2020.02 uses to run a Java configuration

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Previously, the initial command could be seen at the top of the run console, however, nowadays this is not the case.
[image: IntelliJ run window]
Previously the command could be seen in the place of "17.37.50: Executing task 'Main.main()' ...", but it has since disappeared.

I tried to change the "shorten command line" option to "none", but it didn't help.

Is this an issue with IntelliJ itself, or my configuration?

Comment: In this case IDEA uses Gradle to run your command, so you need to check how Gradle is configured. You can switch IDEA over to the old variant where IDEA itself buidls and runs your code directly (check in the Gradle settings of IDEA).

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with the help of Joachim Sauer; answering my own question to help others.

[image: IntelliJ settings; Gradle tab]

In my case, I got it working by selecting "IntelliJ IDEA" instead of "Gradle" in the "Build and run using:"  menu.